# How to convert ONNX back to pth format

Tags: python, pytorch, onnx, fast-ai

I have a model in onnx format, and I want to run it in fastai learner. possibly something like this

```
learn = learn.load('model.onnx')
```

another way is to convert back to pth format, but I dont see any proper library on this task. I need your help in either one of this approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native solution and some people are currently working on it : https://github.com/ENOT-AutoDL/onnx2torch

Also to be clear, a `.pth` checkpoint , usually only contains the parameters such as weights, biases... not the operations like `conv2d`, `batchnorm2d`, `pooling`. An onnx model, in another hand, contains both operations and parameters that's why you can infer them. If, from an onnx, you only need the weights & biases in order to load a state into a torch model already implemented, it might be quite easy, if you want to automatically build a torch model from an onnx, that's the hard part.